# testng - what is the maximum value for priority for @Test annotation

Tags: selenium, testng

I have ordered the automated test in a particular sequence by using the **priority=xxx** in @Test annotation.

For the last class to be tested, the priority values started with 10201 and above.  However, this particular class was tested right after the 1st class with priorities from 1-10.

Does any one have any idea?  I looked at the TestNG documentaion - but the values are not discussed.

Comment: Keep in mind, tests with the lower priority value will be executed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into TestNG source code and looks like priority is an int, so the max value will be 2147483647.

In fact, you can test it easily by running following tests:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class Testing {

    @Test(priority = 2147483647)
    public void testOne() {
        System.out.println("Test One");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void testTwo() {
        System.out.println("Test Two");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.  In that case, why is the last test-class executed right after the first test-class.  According to the priority values, it should be executed last in the sequence.

Comment: How are you executing tests? Do you have test suite?

Comment: Thx, again. Your example shows priorities in one test class - but mine are spread out in multiple test classes as i mentioned in the question.  The collection of test classes are specified within test-suite in a testNG xml file.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Best way would be to create another question and post your test suite file there.